# How to limit the opening of same activity to 5 times?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I have here the homeActivity and when the user taps on one of the products it will intent them to the productsActivity. The productsActivity contains all the product's information and the "Similar Products List (in recyclerview)" and when the user taps again on one of those products it will intent to the same activity but the content of the selected product's info will become the recent selected one. And then the process is still the same when he taps to similar products again. Now I want to limit the opening of the same activity to 5 times only so the user can go back to the last previous 4 products and then to home activity. I know the case of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`setting the activity to `singleTop` but that's not what I wanted because I still want to give the user the previous 4 products that he chooses before going back to homeActivity. Please take a look at this presentation that I created so you can understand the process more clearer.

In order to enable this process, the user must tap to more than 5 different products first.

[image]

After reaching the 6th opened product, the 1st productActivity that have created will be closed or removed. It was like an array on pushing element to the end and removing the first element.

[image]

**Please Note:** The process of this is not limited to 6th opened activity only, the user can open all the products in the list but it will keep 5 opened productsActivity only containing the previous 4 activity that the user taps.

Comment: Why Activity? A combination of pager and fragmnet will solve this easily?

Comment: I thought that the best way is in activity. Can you please elaborate on how can pager and fragment solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need custom back navigation.

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Handle the back button event
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
```

maintain a FIFO queue of size 4 for your activities' states. You can use a Deque, so that you can insert or take from both ends. You can keep this deque in your application. When starting the activity add the state to the queue.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back
The details of implementing custom back navigation

Comment: I am just wondering if this process would produce memory leak? Because the reason why I want to add a condition of 5 activity open only is the constant increase of memory when opening the same activity. BTW thank you for your answer, I will gladly try this!

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get/set the queue size of my activity? And how to use a deque?

Comment: Also is this applicable for Fragment only?